# iPhone: problems resizing image from UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

At the moment, I have a UIImagePickerController set up to take a picture, and return it as a small-sized photo (about 300 x 500ish pixels).

By default, the image obtained from the image picker is full resolution - i.e. quite large. So before doing anything with this image, I resize it:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);

CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

[sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

-

**What doesn't work so well:**

This step is quite resource intensive, in fact it freezes the app for several seconds during the operation. I haven't tried it on an iPhone 4, but I can imagine it will only be worse with HD images.

Aside from being resource intensive, getting this photo also seems to use up a very large amount of memory for a small period of time, often resulting in the app crashing. I am assuming that this memory is from the large sized images that are being captured at first.

-

**So:**

What it the best/standard method of getting small images from UIImagePicker? I don't want my app to freeze or crash due to high CPU or RAM usage. Surely there must be a better, more stable and efficient way?

Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find the Trevor's UIImage categories useful to resize images the right way and not reinventing the wheel. That's what I use and it works great.

[Resize a UIImage the right way](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/)

As for the performance issue, you may call your resize method in the background, or put it in an operation to free your main thread of this work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I just tried the resizing code and it doesn't really seem to be any faster than before though.

Comment: You may call your resize method in the background, or put it in an operation to free your main thread of this work.

Comment: I was hoping not to have to do this, as otherwise I can't show the picture straight away (without a loading icon etc). This is what I ended up doing though :)

Comment: Thanks for the accept. I edited the answer to integrate my comment.